# What do they call a document that's like a resume but bigger?

Tags: resume

Someone asked me to give him my (whatever this is called) a few weeks back, but I can't remember the name of it now and I wanted to bring it up with him again. I don't want to embarrass myself by not knowing the name of it :P I hadn't heard of it the first time he mentioned it either so I went looking and the gist of it was that it's essentially a FULL list of all skills, education, achievements, knowledge, whatever. Doesn't need to be a one-page document, can be bigger.

I've been googling, can't seem to find the right phrases to produce the right answer.

Comment: Curriculum Vitae

Comment: Note that's location specific. What Americans call a resume, us Brits call a CV.

Comment: And what Brits call a CV, in America that's what's known as a "resume".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking is probably [*Curriculum vitae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae).

Resumes are **short and concise**, and usually are intended to capture the attention of possible recruiters, while efficiently presenting your credentials and studies. CV's on the other hand cover **your whole life** most of the times, including most (or all) credential, studies, hobbies and other things that you have done that contribute to your character and professional skills.

Take a look at [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-is-the-difference-between-a-resume-and-a-cv) great question to know more about the differences between them, as the use of those words depends strongly on the context (country) you are.